# White flash when loading page dynamically because of Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, dynamically-generated

I load my pages dynamically with php.

Only the information in my content div changes.

I have a script that changes the background image on refresh.
but it gives a white flash when you navigate through the site.

```
var totalCount = 6;
function ChangeBackground()
{
    var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
    document.body.background = 'background/test/'+num+'.jpg';
}
```

How can i prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m assuming this is an issue of the browser loading the image, and trying to display it before it’s fully downloaded.

Have a look at [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/preloading-and-the-javascript-image-object/5214317) for information on pre-loading images before displaying them.